Reducing .fbx file size with decimate
I'm trying to apply the decimate modifier to reduce the polygon count so that my .fbx file when I export is lighter. However when I apply the modifier, even though my polygon count is reduced significantly my .fbx file is 10 MB larger. Any tips?

I don’t remember all what’s supported in the FBX format, but is there any chance you accidentally threw in some default materials, other objects, or the like?

TheLabCat
The only thing I did was apply the decimate modifier in all objects using a Phyton script and then I exported again to .fbx

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Unfortunately I can't as the model I'm working on is not mine, rather it is property of the company I work for. Is there any additional information I can give that may help without me sharing the file?

Does this effect also happen when you decimate and export other objects? Or is it tied to this object specifically? Does it happen when you apply a Decimate modifier manually and then export or only when you use your python script?

I just tested it now and decimating the same object and exporting reduces file size like you would expect. At least on my end.

How many objects are in your blend file? Make sure you export only your selected object. Can you also try all options for File > Cleanup? Other than that we need more details/clarity on how you can reproduce this otherwise there is no way for us to help. Once you find a way or are able to share a file with this issue we can re-open.
